# Minimum speed detected by Core Location

Tags: ios, core-location

I'm trying to develop an application which displays user speed and some other data.

I want to know what is the minimum speed that Core Location can detect.  When I'm moving in the street it's reading is 0.00.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    //i display some other data here
    speedLbl.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Speed: %f km/hr",([lastLocation speed]*3.6)];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set up `distanceFilter` and `desiredAccuracy` properties.

This is [Jano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412916/jano)'s code

```
self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;

/* Pinpoint our location with the following accuracy:
 *
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation  highest + sensor data
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyBest               highest     
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters   10 meters   
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters      100 meters
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer          1000 meters 
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers    3000 meters
 */
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;

/* Notify changes when device has moved x meters.
 * Default value is kCLDistanceFilterNone: all movements are reported.
 */
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0f;

/* Notify heading changes when heading is > 5.
 * Default value is kCLHeadingFilterNone: all movements are reported.
 */
self.locationManager.headingFilter = 5;

// update location
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Speed calculating:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    double speed = newLocation.speed;

    //another way
    if(oldLocation != nil)
    {
        CLLocationDistance distanceChange = [newLocation getDistanceFrom:oldLocation];
        NSTimeInterval sinceLastUpdate = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:oldLocation.timestamp];
        speed = distanceChange/sinceLastUpdate;

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Osama Khalifa, it depends on how you are using `location manager`.

For `speed` calculation i would prefer you to use `satellite GPS (stopUpdatingLocation`) instead of  `GPS` through `mobile network` `(startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges)` because `GPS` through mobile tower doesn't have `accuracy` in `speed`.

Also you need to set `desiredAccuracy` and `distanceFilter` value to nearest one to get more `accurate` value.

```
Note : more accurate results you ask consume more of iPhone battery power.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no limitation. You have to calculate the speed yourself with:
`distanceChange * timeSpan`

`distanceChange = [newLocation getDistanceFrom:oldLocation]`
`timeSpan = time when retrieved new Location - time when retrieved old Location`

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391589/cllocation-speed) thread!